# structure_dump and structure_load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I don't understand when we would use the `structure_dump` and `structure_load`. There is no information in the Rails documentation:

[`ActiveRecord::Tasks::DatabaseTasks::structure_load`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Tasks/DatabaseTasks.html#method-i-structure_load)

[`ActiveRecord::Tasks::DatabaseTasks::structure_dump`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Tasks/DatabaseTasks.html#method-i-structure_dump)

Can someone explain these methods thoroughly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I'll link to some Rails documentation which may be more helpful. This documentation is about the default Rails rake tasks which utilize the methods you've asked about:

[Types of Rails schema dumps](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#types-of-schema-dumps) (Rails edge guides)

I assume you are familiar with Rails' `db/schema.rb` file. That file is essentially a big "migration" file, which contains some Ruby code which can be run, which will create all the necessary tables and indices in your database. This is what happens when you run `rake db:schema:load`.

We can use `rake db:schema:dump` to essentially take the state of the database and translate it directly into a `schema.rb` file. We might need to do this if we don't have any migration files, and we don't have an existing `schema.rb` file. In some cases (not very many), ActiveRecord has trouble properly "translating" the database schema directly into Ruby code. ActiveRecord is unable to translate certain features/options, including, but not limited to:

- [Triggers](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-trigger-student-database/)
- [Stored Procedures](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-procedures/)
- [CHECK Constraints](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-check-constraint/)

`structure_dump` and it's accompanying rake task `db:structure:dump` exist to try to solve this problem. Instead of asking ActiveRecord's database adapter to dump to a `schema.rb` file containing Ruby code, it instead uses the database's underlying management tools to dump to a `structure.sql` file, containing a big list of SQL statements. It's typically easier to "represent" the database schema in raw SQL instead of having to translate it into Ruby code first. The resulting `structure.sql` file can now be used to recreate the database schema/structure in one of two ways:

- Run the contents of `db/structure.sql` in an SQL prompt, or in some way which is directly evaluated by your database management system
- Run the rake task `db:structure:load`. This will read from `db/structure.sql` and evaluate it's contents as raw SQL, but through ActiveRecord - very similar to `db:schema:load`.

**NOTE:** In Rails 6.1, `db:structure:dump` and `db:structure:load` are [deprecated](https://blog.bigbinary.com/2020/09/22/rails-6-1-deprecates-rails-db-structure-dump.html). In 6.1 and later, the schema type is configurable in your environment configuration:

```rb
config.active_record.schema_format = :sql
```

This will switch the normal `db:schema:load` and `db:schema:dump` to use SQL formats instead.

---

**TLDR:** Sometimes it's hard for ActiveRecord to dump a schema directly to Ruby code, so `structure_dump` allows dumping to raw SQL. That SQL can be run to recreate the database schema the same way that a `schema.rb` is run to recreate the database schema. You can load it into the database as raw SQL or by running the rake task `db:structure:load`. In Rails 6.1, [this is changing](https://blog.bigbinary.com/2020/09/22/rails-6-1-deprecates-rails-db-structure-dump.html).

Comment: Might be worth noting that `db:structure:dump` uses the database's native tools so it will dump the database structure as the database sees it rather than just as ActiveRecord sees it so `db:structure:dump` will include things that ActiveRecord doesn't know about (such as triggers, stored procedures, CHECK constraints, ...).

Comment: @muistooshort think I touched on some parts of that but I definitely need to make it clearer that it's using the database's native tools. Thanks!

Comment: @taylorthurlow Very nice explanation